# shouldChangeCharactersInRange with special separation

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create special `UITextField` where the text will be separated after some amount of characters. I know that `-shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate from `UITextField` can be used.

Now, I need some more complex separation while typing the text in the `UITextField`. I need the characters separated by one **whitespace** after every 4 characters. Last 2 characters should also be separated with one **whitespace** from the rest.

**Example:** XXNL XNLX XLMD XMLD XX

I know I have to use this method...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

But don't know what to do with this method. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: try to save previous character and compare current character and previous character is space then return No otherwise allow.Space after a character is allowed and space after a space is not allowed.

Comment: Yes i have tried this one. Only the spaces should be added automatically. The user must type the value like normal and the system should add the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In that delegate method you should build the string that the textField contains.
Then, you can check if the length of the string modulo 5 is 4 (so that after 4 characters it fires, and after 9 characters (4 + 1 space + other 4) it fires again and so on. If the check fires, you append a space @" " on the textField text.

The problem with doing this is that if the user moves the cursor and changes the text, then everything gets lost.

Another way you can do this is then to trim the string (remove all the spaces) in the same method, and then add the spaces again every 4 characters

Answer (score -1):

```
See if you want that style of text then after every 4 characters in textfield text just add one space.and if length is total characters you want then don't allow any other characters.In shouldchangecharactersinRange: you have to insert 1 space programatically

if(textfield.text.length % 4 == 0) then 
    string = [string stringbyappendingstring:@""];

Do this it will fix your requirement and dont accept any characters after the length you need,like

if(textfield.text.length == someinteger) then 
     don't accept the string just return NO;
```